# FullCalendar popover other events conflict

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5, popover

I am running FullCalendar v6 using resourceTimeGridDay.

Using the 'eventDidMount' event render hook I am calling a JS function for popovers on each event to show details of the event. The popover is shown on hover and I would like it to remain visible until the mouse moves out of the popover area. I have this working correctly except when there are events 'under' the popover, this then opens the popover for the event under the popover when I would like to interact with the original popover....

Anyway I am sure I have used to work popover way too much! Here is my code that 'eventDidMount' calls:

```
function eventPopover(event) {
        $(function () {
            $(event.el).popover({
                title: 'the title2',
                content: 'content',
                placement: 'bottom',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                animation: true,
            }).on("mouseenter", function () {
                            var _this = this;
                            $(this).popover("show");
                            $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                                $(_this).popover('hide');
                            });
                        }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                            var _this = this;
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                                    $(_this).popover("hide");
                                }
                            }, 300);
                        });
        })
    
}
```

---

After Meghshyam Sonar's answer I am getting the following response.

[new response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYjzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

What I recently encountered was nesting a pop-up box in the popover. And nested popovers also need to trigger events, But fullcalendar bound a mouse press event to the document。 When pressed, it will cause the destruction of its built-in popper component。This will result in my own defined popover component event not being triggered，So after thinking for a long time。I have intercepted the global events here。And intercepted and modified the events he bound.